# Is it possible to set a maximum number of retries shared between all pool connections in the same session?

Tags: session, request, python-requests, grequests

Currently I do the following for setting a maximum number of connection retries for my `grequest` wrapper:

```
self._s = Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504])
self._s.mount('http://, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
```

I then create a bunch of `grequest` objects with the session `self._s` as one of the arguments. For exmaple, creating a set of `GET` requests would be done using something like this:

`requests = [grequests.get(url, ..., 'session': self._s')]`

Finally, these are all eventually issued using `grequests.map(requests, ...)`.

The problem is I want a way of making the maximum number of retries persist and be shared across all connections of a connection pool. The retries still seem to be applied only on an individual connection basis. Is there any possible way of doing this? Is this not possible since new `Retry()` objects seem to be created upon each decrement from total calls?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck. The `Retry` docstring says (excerpt):

> Each retry attempt will create a new Retry object with updated values, so they can be safely reused.

So a new object is made, like you said, every connection...and that's done by design.

Furthermore, the `Retry` object itself is what allows for the threading: it sleeps between connection attempts. So one `Retry` object *must* be associated with one thread, by this design. Sorry. Here's a link to [`urllib.utils.retry`](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/util/retry.py) in case that helps.